# Multiple counts on single grouped values

Tags: mysql

I have a table which records the points scored by players in a game (eg Table 1). I am trying to write a query which will COUNT the number of times each score was achieved by each player (eg Results 1). I can easily do this for one of the points values :-

```
SELECT name, COUNT(*) AS 10s FROM points WHERE points = '10' GROUP BY name
```

but can't work out how to then include all three points values. Is it possible, and if so could someone help me out?

Many thanks

Jules

```
Table 1
+---------+-----+
| name | points |
| John | 10     |
| Pete | 5      |
| Anna | 10     |
| John | 10     |
| Pete | 0      |
| Anna | 5      |
| John | 5      |
| Pete | 5      |
| Anna | 0      |
+---------+-----+

Results 1
+------+-----+----+-----+
| name | 10s | 5s |  0s |
| John | 2   | 1  |  0  |
| Pete | 0   | 2  |  1  |
| Anna | 1   | 1  |  1  |
+------+-----+----+-----+
```

Comment: `SUM(points=10),SUM(points=5),SUM(points=0)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `sum()` to add up where your conditions are `true`

```
SELECT name, 
       sum(points = 10) AS 10s,
       sum(points = 5) AS 5s,
       sum(points = 0) AS 0s
FROM points 
GROUP BY name
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks. I was hung up on COUNT!